# Uploading Images Resize

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a huge image that is going to be uploaded to my server. The width and height are for example: `2000x2000`. I have multiple places in my code where I need the image to be `1000x1000`, `250 x 110` or like `100 x 50`. When they upload the image, should I make ASP automatically re size to these dimensions and save them on my webserver like `image-250x110`, `image-1000x1000`, `image-original`, and `image-100x50` or is it fine to just to get the original image and re size on the fly through the code then show it to the users. I'm asking this because I'm worried that if too many people go on your website, re sizing the original huge image all the time would take alot of processing power and slow down the app. Or would something like this would be fine: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfWeek11ImageResizerEnablesCleanClearImageResizingInASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your certainly want to resize the image when its uploaded since resizing a huge image of 2000 by 2000 pixels can easily take 2 seconds, even on a fast server. That's a delay your users are unlikely to appreciate.

Comment: The ImageResizer thing he posted resizes images and caches it, and it does the same or better job than  "Save For Web" in photoshop. So that 2000px image will be served up as 250x110 as < 30k.

Comment: ImageResizer seems to do a good job on resizing. And caching can be a good compromise between resizing after upload and on-the-fly. However, if you have a page with 100 images that aren't cached in the required size - for whatever reason - and they all take about 1 second to resize on average, then it will bog down your server. Caching isn't always sufficient.

Comment: It will always depend on the application and purpose. Sometimes having one version and resizing/caching is the solution, sometimes resizing on upload + saving the multiple versions is the solution. He can do both, as I specified in my answer. But you have a good point.

Answer (score 1):

What you posted, [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/), is going to be your best solution, for many reasons, including:

1. There are a lot of potential problems when writing your own resizer, as detailed in [20 Image Resizing Pitfalls](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2009/20-image-resizing-pitfalls), including performance and stability issues.
2. If you redesign your site and want to change those image dimensions... it will be painful.
3. With ImageResizer, you only have one image - the nice big original image. All subsequent versions are served up (and cached) via the URL call. Note that the cacheable-version of ImageResizer requires a license.
4. ImageResizer will likely do a better job resizing images than yours will, both in quality and in file size, and also comes with filters, watermarking, and other features.
5. Resizing on the fly is a really bad option as it will eat up CPU.
6. If you can't pay for the cacheable version, you CAN use ImageResizer to resize the images on upload and save off the 3 versions or so of the images that you want.

I've used both methods -- written my own and used ImageResizer... ImageResizer is the way to go in my opinion.

Comment: Now that's the problem, I need to dish out 300$ for the image resizer which would be a good investment but unfortunately I need to determine if the website I'm making would work in the longrun and see if it'll be profitable.

Comment: @MohamadBataineh the free version works just like the regular one, except it would do processing on the fly which can have performance issues for the web server.

Comment: @MohamadBataineh plus you can just use ImageResizer to resize the images on upload, like you wanted, and then just serve up those static files.

Comment: I'll probably just use the free version for now and if I get a considerable amount of people, I can upgrade to the cache version. Thanks for the information!